# Setting a CEdit control text value and it word-wrap

Tags: mfc, multiline, word-wrap, cedit

I have a `CEdit` control and I have it set as **multiline** in the resources.

The user can type text and if it is too wide for the control it will word wrap. Great.

Now, I know that I can pass in a string and include new line characters like `\n` to cause it to show text of multiple lines.

But if I have a single line of text, that is too long, it will not work wrap. :( So how do I deal with that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/d673af1917e903c2.htm).

I had to set the `ES_AUTOHSCROLL` property to false.

Now it works:

[image: Edit control - wordwrap]

Comment: Cancel/OK order looks more like Mac style, not Windows.

Comment: WS_HSCROLL should also be removed.